# ASPNET_REGIIS Encrypted connection string working in one server, but not working in other sever

Tags: .net, web-config, aspnet-regiis.exe

Encrypted the connection strings in Web.config using ASPNET_REGIIS -pef / -pdf  utility,

The Connection in web.config working fine in one server but not working on second similar server when copied.

Both are Windows Server 2016 and have .Net framework 4.7

Decryption command on second server saying parameter missing, where as same command with same web.config file works fine in first server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASPNET_REGIIS command pef/pdf are specific to machine/server. We cannot copy encrypted web.config form one server to other server.

```
::Encryption
ASPNET_REGIIS -pdf "connectionStrings" "D:\webroot"
::Decryption    
ASPNET_REGIIS -pef "connectionStrings" "D:\webroot"
```

Need to run encryption  commands separately in each servers.